# Two-variable continuous function which results in an integer if and only if arguments are integer

Tags: nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, special-functions, integer-sequences, multivariable-calculus

I am  looking for functions $f(x,y)$, real arguments, continuous,
with the following properties:

1. $f(m,n) = r$, where $r$ is integer $> 0$ if and only if $m,n$ are integers $> 0$.
2. $f(m,n) \le f(r,s)$ if and only if $m n \le r  s$, with $m,n,r,s$ integers $> 0$.

I would like to know if functions with properties 1 alone, 2 alone, or both together exist, and if they have been studied and given a specific name (for further investigation). In particular, I would be curious to know if relatively simple closed-form functions satisfying both conditions exist, or can exist at all.

If useful to allow existence, the further constraints $m < n, r < s$ can be used.

Comment: Nine versions in one hour does not inspire confidence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such functions as you require do not exist.  Your requirements impose that $f(1,1) < f(1,2) < f(2,2)$ (for example, $f(1,1) \leq f(1,2)$ by (2), but $\neg (f(1,2) \leq f(1,1))$ also by (2), so we have $f(1,1) < f(1,2)$).  Now consider the continuous function $x \mapsto f(x,x)$ on $[1,2]$: by the intermediate value theorem, there exists $x$ with $1<x<2$ such that $f(x,x) = f(1,2)$.  Since $f(1,2)$ is an integer but $f(x,x)$ is not by your requirement (1), this is a contradiction.

Comment: I am trying to understand. Sorry, I think a got a bit lost in your proof. if you use f(x,x) where the arguments are equal (like moving on a diagonal), how can we apply it to the values [1,2] which are distinct?

Comment: Note that $[1,2]$ is a compact interval, not a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: That is right, I meant actually the values 1, 2, like in f(1,2). f(x,x) seems to be moving over the diagonal of the domain. So the proof seems if I am understanding right, is limited to restricting to equal arguments, f(1,2) cannot be represented as f(x,x), no?)

Comment: I see that we are now on version 8 of this question. It took me two minutes to answer the original question, essentially by the same method as @Gro-Tsen. It is trivial to find continuous functions satisfying just 1 or just 2. I vote to close.

Comment: Thanks please provide some examples of these trivial functions. That was the purpose of the question. Note that as to point 2, it must hold only for integers, the condition is not required for nonintegers. Dave, I do not see your answer which one is it ? (Note that the question is always the same, only refinements to make it clearer and cleaner for the site.)

Comment: @Jada Yes, $f(x,x)$ is the diagonal value, and $f(1,2)$ is an off-diagonal value. My argument is that because $f(1,1) < f(1,2) < f(2,2)$, by the intermediate value theorem, there must be a diagonal value $f(x,x)$ with $1<x<2$ which is equal to the off-diagonal $f(1,2)$, which is impossible because one is supposed to be an integer and the other isn't, so your two conditions cannot hold simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you. I can see now your argument. Actually being "off-diagonal" is crucial to it. Can you also provide some simple examples of functions satisfying condition 1? Thanks again.

Comment: @Jada: The continuous function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ which takes a point $P \in \mathbb{R}^2$ to $1 + \min(\frac{1}{2}, d(P,\mathbb{N}_{>0}^2))$ where $d(P,\mathbb{N}_{>0}^2)$ denotes the distance from $P$ to the closest point of the form $(m,n)$ with $m,n>0$ integers, takes the value $1$ exactly on those points, and is otherwise strictly between $1$ and $2$, so it satisfies your condition (1).

Comment: I see thank you. It would be more useful for practical purposes a less trivial function that at each pair would assign a different integer, so that it can be used to "enumerate" pairs.

Comment: @Jada The argument in my answer shows essentially that you can't have more than two different values on the positive integer pairs if you impose condition (1): if you have $u<v<w$ at such points, find a continuous path between the point with value $u$ and that with value $w$ that avoids the integer pair points, and somewhere you will hit the value $v$ and get a contradiction.

Comment: @Jada, condition 2 requires $f(m,n) = f(r,s)$ when $mn=rs$ and they're all integers.

Comment: It seems to me that for instance, the pairing function used by Cantor can enumerate pairs using an integer index (what I was looking for by condition 1). [Sure, in that case then the pairs cannot be ordered by product.]